# Magento: how do I add an additional multiselect in admin config settings for a shipping module?

Tags: magento

In Magento admin custom shipping controller I can include a nice multiselect for selecting countries with the following in system.xml:

```
<specificcountry translate="label">
    <label>Ship to Specific countries</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>91</sort_order>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</specificcountry>
```

I want to include another multiselect in the admin config settings for my own fieldset, possibly with an extra set of values in their own table. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you have to do it the same way but to write your own source_model.

Comment: I think I can manage that for some of my options, any idea how I can pull through states/counties/provinces for a given country?

Comment: Please also read about [source models here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#source_model).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650487/magento-system-config-add-custom-value-in-multiselect